# use JavaScript to manipulate multiple (predictably) named DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to execute a function repeatedly on groups of predictably named html divs.

I am using a drag and drop relationship shown below in which dragging text into a certain div space "target" causes that text to appear in another div called "saves".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OnDragStart (event) {
            if (event.dataTransfer) {
                var format = "Text";
                var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData (format);


            }
        }

        function OnDropTarget (event) {
            if (event.dataTransfer) {
                var format = "Text";
                var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData (format);
                if (!textData) {
                    textData = "<span style='color:red'>The data transfer contains no text data.</span>";
                }

                var savesDiv = document.getElementById ("saves");
                savesDiv.innerHTML = savesDiv.innerHTML + "<br />" + textData;
            }
            else {
                alert ("Your browser does not support the dataTransfer object.");
            }

            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation ();
            }
            else {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

- The script in combination with the corresponding html works perfectly for the target and saved divs... but what i would  really like is to apply the same script to a set of divs pairs named 
  (target1, saves1 )
  (target2, saves2)
  (target3,saves3)
  (target4 saves4) etc etc
  with numbers in div ids going up every time by 1 up to (target20, saves 20)  ... Without obviously repeating the same script 20 times with different id names when referring to all the target and saved divs.
- I realize this is a total newbie question but I'm really interested to learn the different ways this can be approached.

Comment: would i maybe create an array with numbers 1-20 and plug that in somehow so that it applies to each instance of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a common class name to these divs so when the dragdrop event occurs, it can be handled using the class name instead of the id; that is, like `$('.someClass').someEvent` instead of `$('#target1')`. You can get its id property  inside this function using `$(this).attr("id")`.

So if you have "target1" as the id, get the last character ("1") using the JavaScript `substring` function; you can write generic code such as this:

```
$('.someClass').someEvent(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr(id);
  var lastno=id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("t"),id.length);

  //now rest of code
  $("#saves"+lastno).val($("#target"+lastno).val());
});
```

Comment: Thankyou This appears to go in the right direction mainly, i like the idea of using the findthis id and last number to link the two...  the only thing that i see as a problem with the second part is that i dont think the value of ~target+lastno changes in the script because actually its just a drop spot really a place i drop the text which actually doesnt ever fill itself, although maybe im misunderstandign something

Comment: if you could make jsfiddle we may understand your problem better